# Typescript (seemingly) choosing the wrong overload

Tags: typescript

I have a method like this:

```js
class Foo {
    public runInWorker(cb: () => void): void;
    public runInWorker(cb: () => Promise<void>): void | Promise<void>;
    public runInWorker(cb: () => void | Promise<void>): void | Promise<void> {
        if (cluster.isPrimary ?? cluster.isMaster) {
            return;
        }

        return cb();
    }
}
```

What I want to do is to pass in a sync or async function and I want the overload to return the correct type (i.e. `void` for a sync function and `Promise<void>` for an async function).

This works fine for a sync callback:

```js
// result is void
const result = new Foo().runInWorker(() => {})
```

But it fails with an async callback:

```js
// result is void, but it should be Promise<void>
const result = new Foo().runInWorker(async () => {})
```

How do I fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure precisely why, but a function returning a promise of void is type-convertible to a function returning void (I suppose because the return value of a function returning void should never be used, so a function `A`-which-returns-non-void with compatible parameter signature to function `B` is compatible with `B` if / even if `B` returns void). The opposite is not true:

```js
const ok: () => void = async () => {};
const notOk: () => Promise<void> = () => {};
```

[The TypeScript handbook section on function overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads) says:

> In order for the compiler to pick the correct type check, it follows a similar process to the underlying JavaScript. It looks at the overload list and, proceeding with the first overload, attempts to call the function with the provided parameters. If it finds a match, it picks this overload as the correct overload. For this reason, it’s customary to order overloads from most specific to least specific.

As I mentioned at the beginning, your overload which takes a sync callback and returns void can accept a sync *or* async callback. The overload which takes an async callback can only accept an async callback and not a sync callback, which makes it the "more specific" overload.

So to fix your problem, I'm pretty sure you can just reorder your overloads as so:

```js
class Foo {
    public runInWorker(cb: () => Promise<void>): void | Promise<void>;
    public runInWorker(cb: () => void): void;
    public runInWorker(cb: () => void | Promise<void>): void | Promise<void> {
        return cb();
        // ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Use generics instead

```
class Foo {
  public runInWorker<T>(cb: () => T): T {
    return cb();
  }
}
```

Comment: notice that their async overload can also return void. Assuming that is intentional and not some kind of cludge to get something working, this answer does not account for that.

Answer (score 0):

First up, the problem is probably this line:

```
    public runInWorker(cb: () => Promise<void>): void | Promise<void>;
```

If you pass a function returning a promise, the return value should be a promise, so change it to

```
    public runInWorker(cb: () => Promise<void>): Promise<void>;
```

However, it could seem that there is a code smell here, as it seems to me that you mix promises and callbacks in a strange way.

You should *either* work with callbacks *or* promises, not both. I.e. it's fine to have a function that can take either a callback as input and return nothing - or take no callback as input, and return a promise. But callbacks that returns promises is a strange mix of styles.

So I could deal with this in this way

```
public run(cb: (err: Error, data: Data) => void): void;
public run(): Promise<Data>;
public run(cb?: (err: Error, data: Data) => void): void | Promise<Data> {
  // In this version, the function is natively implemented with callbacks,
  // so we wrap that in a promise here.
  if (!cb) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.run((err, data) => err ? reject(err) : resolve(data))
    })
  }

  // Here the rest of the function that natively works with a callback
}
```

Comment: I think a possible point of confusion is whether their "callback" is really a callback. Where is their "run" implementation? I'm guessing it's inside the body of the "callback". If it's really a callback and they just cropped out the code which does the running, then I agree that it smells like antipattern. But otherwise, this falls into the category of functions like `Promise.all`, `Promise.any`, `Promise.race`, etc. @Lehks would you care to comment?